# Is Tree the right data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I must create a basic calendar of one year. I thought to use a generic Tree with the year like root, months as children of root, days as children of months etc...

Is it the right way?

I receive data of calendar from a library calendar of Python. For some days, or hours I must associate some events and I must represent the calendar with their events, in a table for example (every days of the calendar, days without events too).

Comment: You can't make this decision without knowing how you're going to consume whatever data you put in the calendar.

Comment: What language are you using? Is this a homework assignment? You haven't provided nearly enough information to answer your overly broad question.

Comment: I must represent the calendar and each element (day or month or hour) could have some event and I must represent events too

Comment: You might be better off with just a List of CalendarEvents.  It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you [edit] your question and add a lot more details?

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't the right way.  In some sense, using a tree is a *premature optimization* over using a simple collection.  You can always add a tree or other indexing data structure later.

In the absence of any further information you should use the simplest possible data structure: a simple collection.  I'd recommend using a simple table as you'll find in SQL, with rows and columns: columns like start date/time, end date/time, event type, event name, etc...

As your knowledge of the domain expands, you'll be zeroing in on which columns and which tables to have.  Using a tree will hamper your agility — your ability to change as your project scope grows — whereas using a collection will not (and at worst, a collection will hamper your performance, and that's fixable).

When starting out, initially focus on the ***what*** of the domain, rather the ***how***.  ***What*** columns, rather than ***how*** to organize (hierarchical) structure, how to insert, how to search.  If you need some optimized data structure or index, that can be done later.

Calendars imply long-term persistence anyway, which also suggests tables (and a database of some sort).  (With a database you can index your date columns for better performance if you find you need it.)

Eventually, you'll have a good understanding of the consuming application's query and command patterns, and its performance!  Now you can consider caching, other data structures, etc...

---

On another note, a tree as you describe will be very cumbersome.  (Another reason to start with a simple collection, and optimize something later.)

- What if you have a two day meeting that goes from the 31st to the 1st?
- Following your logic: Are you going to represent hours as children of days, minutes as children of hours, seconds as children of minutes, etc..?